# Is there a way to make python become interactive in the middle of a script?

Tags: python, scripting, interactive

I'd like to do something like:

```
do lots of stuff to prepare a good environement
become_interactive
#wait for Ctrl-D
automatically clean up
```

Is it possible with python?If not, do you see another way of doing the same thing?

Comment: Thanks to all! For the record, the easiest way to use the code module to achieve this is the following:

    import code
    code.interact(local=globals())

Comment: To get local variables into the namespace as well, you need 

`code.interact(local=dict(globals(), **locals())`.

Note the addition of `**locals`.  I was wondering this question myself, and your comment was the best answer I found :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With IPython v1.0, you can simply use

```
from IPython import embed
embed()
```

with more options shown in the [docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#embedding-ipython).

Comment: You can use this anywhere and it preserves the scope.

Comment: I whish I had known this before ! Thank you

Answer (score 12):

Use the -i flag when you start Python and set an atexit handler to run when cleaning up.

File script.py:

```
import atexit
def cleanup():
    print "Goodbye"
atexit.register(cleanup)
print "Hello"
```

and then you just start Python with the -i flag:

```
C:\temp>\python26\python -i script.py
Hello
>>> print "interactive"
interactive
>>> ^Z

Goodbye
```

Answer (score 9):

The [`code`](http://docs.python.org/library/code.html) module will allow you to start a Python REPL.

Answer (score 7):

To elaborate on IVA's answer:  [embedding-a-shell](http://writeonly.wordpress.com/2008/09/08/embedding-a-python-shell-in-a-python-script/), incoporating `code` and Ipython.

```
def prompt(vars=None, message="welcome to the shell" ):
    #prompt_message = "Welcome!  Useful: G is the graph, DB, C"
    prompt_message = message
    try:
        from IPython.Shell import IPShellEmbed
        ipshell = IPShellEmbed(argv=[''],banner=prompt_message,exit_msg="Goodbye")
        return  ipshell
    except ImportError:
        if vars is None:  vars=globals()
        import code
        import rlcompleter
        import readline
        readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
        # calling this with globals ensures we can see the environment
        print prompt_message
        shell = code.InteractiveConsole(vars)
        return shell.interact

p = prompt()
p()
```

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly the thing you want but python `-i` will start interactive prompt after executing the script.

> `-i`     : inspect interactively after running script, (also PYTHONINSPECT=x) and force prompts, even if stdin does not appear to be a terminal

```
$ python -i your-script.py
Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Jan 20 2010, 21:44:03) 
...
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

You may call python itself:

```
import subprocess

print "Hola"

subprocess.call(["python"],shell=True)

print "Adios"
```